# Resize a Chart Object with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I want to resize a `Chart` object. I am creating a graph from a set of data in Excel and inserting the graph in a Word doc via VBA.

I tried to use `.Width` property from the `ChartObjects` object but I couldn't extend this to chart. ( I got an application error with `ws1.ChartObjects`.)

```
Sub CPU_Top_10_Chart()

Dim wdApp   As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc   As Word.Document
Dim cht     As Chart
Dim ws1     As Worksheet

 Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add("C:\...\chart_test.docx")

 Set cht = Charts.Add
 Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

 With cht

        .SetSourceData Source:=ws1.Range("A2:C12")
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

End With

cht.CopyPicture
wdDoc.Bookmarks("insert_chart").Range.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems, you're trying to paste image into word document instead of linked chart.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do this with VBA. But I want to resize the Chart.

Comment: Inside word document or sheet?

Comment: I am trying to insert the chart to a Word doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call "Worksheet.Shapes.AddChart" to create the chart and set the size:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, Width:=100, Height:=100)
  With .Chart
    .SetSourceData ws1.Range("A2:C12")
  End With
  .CopyPicture
End With
```

Comment: So don't use `Chart` and just try it with `Shapes` object?

Comment: A `Chart` is a `Shape` and some properties like the height and width are only available on the `Shape`.

Comment: The `chart` is contained within a special `shape` called a `chartobject`. The `chartobject` has all the properties of a `shape`. You can access the `chartobject` using `chart.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I added

```
Set cht = ws1.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, Width:=300, Height:=300).Chart
```